# WPF - Auto formatting custom types how? (ControlTemplate, Style..)

Tags: wpf, styles

**EDIT:** Solution in code can be found on bottom.

I am not sure if I am "thinking wrong". Assume I have a `ListBox`, and I want to add different stuff to this `ListBox`. Of course, I know I could change the `ItemTemplate`, add some data binding to it, to display my custom classes.

But this is to "special". I am looking for a way to create a "default" look for my `DataWrapper`, independent on where it is used.

If I try to create a style for it, he is complaining that the class does not descend from `FrameworkElement`. Ok, easy way, make `DataWrapper` child of `FrameworkElement`. But this "feels wrong", as this is a business object, not a UI element.

I am a little bit stuck, I know there must be a way to tell WPF how to render elements it does not know. Currently it displays the full class name.

So what is the simplest way to get e.g. the `DataWrapper` as `TextBlock` with green background, the `DataWrapper2` as `TextBlock` with blue background. Displaying the Data string.
I know binding and all this stuff, I am just stuck with how to tell WPF:

If one of your children is a `DataWrapper`, please render it this way. If it is `DataWrapper2`, please render this way...

Here some tryout code:

```
public class DataWrapper
{
    public string Data { get; set; }
}

public class DataWrapper2
{
    public string Data { get; set; }
}

public static class ListBoxTest
{
    public static ListBox CreateTestInstance()
    {
        var lB = new ListBox();

        var items = new ObservableCollection<object>
                        {
                            23.5,
                            "Hello World",
                            new Button() {Content = "Click me"},
                            new DataWrapper() {Data = "Some text"},
                            new DataWrapper2() {Data = "Other text"},
                            "string again"
                        };

        lB.ItemsSource = items;

        var dT = CreateDataTemplate();

        lB.Resources.Add(dT.DataTemplateKey, dT);
        return lB;
    }

    public static DataTemplate CreateDataTemplate()
    {
        var dT = new DataTemplate(typeof(DataWrapper));
        var elementFactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBlock));
        elementFactory.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, new Binding("Data"));

        dT.VisualTree = elementFactory;

        return dT;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [DataTemplate.DataType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatemplate.datatype.aspx).  From the docs: "When you set this property to the data type without specifying an x:Key, the DataTemplate gets applied automatically to data objects of that type."

For finer control, you could also use a [DataTemplateSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, I knew it wasn't that hard. Just got lost a little bit in all my tryouts... Updated code, if anyone else wants to know how..